# Debug or Release what files should I copy to target location in nuget packaging for uwp apps?

Tags: uwp, nuget, nuget-package

I am creating a NuGet package for consumption for all my uwp apps. I have done using release files and it works great, but I am not sure, what files(Debug or Release) should I copy to target location in NuGet packaging for uwp apps? Since, in the documentation example by Microsoft, they use only debug files. why do they copy only the debug files? why not release files? What I learned/thought from my past is, I should deliver only the release contents/components to the clients. What should I do?

- Copy Debug files
- Copy Release files
- Copy Both (Debug & Release files, If so, how?)

[image]

I read similar questions here in StackOverflow, but I could not get answer to my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Release

Debug/Release is a build configuration. When you're debugging your code you are building using the Debug configuration so you get extra debugging information and no optimizations so the code runs slower. However as soon as you want to release something you should be building against Release. This strips out some of the debugging and allows optimizations which speeds up the code. You should never use a Debug build in NuGet, there is no reason.

Source: CoolDadTx's [answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/604242d9-7440-4823-9b12-d844ce89b4c1/debug-or-release-what-files-should-i-copy-to-target-location-in-nuget-packaging-for-uwp-apps?forum=csharpgeneral#b5f32d41-1591-44f1-aaf2-2280c1c91b2f)